# create interval in query and return if valid

Tags: mysql, sql

I've basically got a mySQL table with the following columns:

**time** which is int(11) and will hold a specified value (an amount of seconds)

**package** which is int(11) and will hold another specified value (an amount of actions to be performed over a day)

**last_run** which is int(11) and will hold a datetime value on which the `SELECT` query row was last used

An example of the table would be like so

```
time     |     package    |        last_run
--------------------------------------------------
86400    |      1000      |    0000-00-00 00:00:00
86400    |      1000      |    0000-00-00 00:00:00
86400    |      1000      |    0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I want to basically do a `SELECT` query like the following

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `table` 
WHERE 
    `divide time by package` AS total_seconds_between_each_run 
AND 
    `last_run` OLDER THAN (NOW() / total_seconds_each_run)
```

so the idea I want to do is only grab rows which are older than the `total_seconds_between_each_run` as I only want an action be performed every specified interval

I understand the syntax is not correct on the **mySQL** query, but that's the "example" of which I would like to do if possible using mySQL

**EDIT**

Would something like the following work?

```
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_run)) > (time / package)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to divide `NOW()` by seconds per run -- you already did the division when you calculated that. You want to subtract.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE last_run < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (time/package) SECOND)
```

Your calculation  in the EDIT using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is equivalent, so it should work.

Comment: Thank you, would I also be able to do the following? `AND last_run < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (total_seconds/(package/10)) SECOND)`

Comment: Of course you can. You can combine any expressions with `AND`, why would this be an exception?